# How to detect if media player is running

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I am currently making an app the will control how to start and stop the mediaplayer on Android devices. Only music. I only want my service running when the music player is active in the background or in the front. I want to do this to save on battery life so its not running the whole time.

I have come across this AudioManager.isMusicActive() a few times, but not sure if that is ONLY for if the music is playing in the background.

For some background, my app will start, stop, skip songs, and pause music.

Comment: My app will be using several sensors, and I'm wanting to do this so the sensors aren't active the whole time

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to control when your service is running is to start it when a song starts and stop it when a song finishes or is paused.  This will help you not have to poll to see if music is currently running.

However, if you absolutely have to poll to see if a service is running you can use the following:

```
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (YourServiceClass.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                service_running = true;
            }
        }
```